# Error trying to use a textview and a radiogroup within an LinearLayout

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am making a layout within Xamarin Android, but I find a problem and it is that when using a LinearLayout to group a text view and a radio group, the radio group is not generated on the screen only the text view, that is It seems that the radio group did not exist. 
This is my Qr.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            
            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar1"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar">
            </include>
            
            
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1014dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
                    android:text="Odometro dañado"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:id="@+id/Lbl_odometro">
                </TextView>

                <RadioGroup 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="717dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/radio_3"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
            
                    <RadioButton 
                        android:id="@+id/radio_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Si"
                        android:onClick="radioButton_OnClick">
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton 
                        android:id="@+id/radio_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="No"
                        android:onClick="radioButton_OnClick">
                    </RadioButton>
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="692dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="255dp"
                        android:text="Tapa dañada"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:id="@+id/Lbl_Mensaje">
                    </TextView>

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="717dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="255dp"
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_meat"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                
                        <RadioButton 
                            android:id="@+id/checkbox_meat_1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Si"
                            android:onClick="radioButton_OnClick">
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton 
                            android:id="@+id/checkbox_meat_2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="No"
                            android:onClick="radioButton_OnClick">
                        </RadioButton>
                    </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>

            
            
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <EDMTDev.ZXingXamarinAndroid.ZXingScannerView
        android:id="@+id/zxscan"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <EDMTDev.ZXingXamarinAndroid.ZXingScannerView
            android:id="@+id/zxscan"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout_result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px" >
        </EDMTDev.ZXingXamarinAndroid.ZXingScannerView>
    </EDMTDev.ZXingXamarinAndroid.ZXingScannerView>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_result"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility = "invisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried using a RelativeLayout for grouping, but the problem is that when I generate a background for it, it makes the whole layout get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RadioGroup` could do like "LinearLayout". You could try the xml below.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Odometro dañado"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Si"
                android:onClick="radioButton_OnClick">
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:onClick="radioButton_OnClick">
            </RadioButton>
        </RadioGroup>
        <TextView
            android:text="Tapa dañada"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_meat">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_meat_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Si"
                android:onClick="radioButton_OnClick">
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_meat_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:onClick="radioButton_OnClick">
            </RadioButton>
        </RadioGroup>


    </RadioGroup>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout >
```

Screenshot:

[image]